# Laravel Query Builder: How do I sort results by date - first with ascending order by future dates and then by descending order by past dates?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a model `tasks` with complete tasks with `datetime` in the past and upcoming tasks with `datetime` in the future.

While retrieving the tasks, I want to display the upcoming tasks arranged in ascending order (from now to the future) and tasks in the past in descending order (from now to the past).

```
public function getTasks()
{
        $futureTasks = Task::whereDate('datetime', '>', Carbon::now())->orderBy('datetime', 'asc')->get();
        $pastTasks   = Task::whereDate('datetime', '<', Carbon::now())->orderBy('datetime', 'desc')->get();
        $tasks       = array_merge($futureTasks, $pastTasks);
        $response    = ['tasks' => $tasks];
        // return...
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

> array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array

If I reverse the order of arguments for array_push function, I still get the same error.

```
 public function getTasks()
{
        $futureTasks = Task::whereDate('datetime', '>', Carbon::now())->orderBy('datetime', 'asc')->get();
        $pastTasks   = Task::whereDate('datetime', '<', Carbon::now())->orderBy('datetime', 'desc')->get();
        $tasks       = array_merge($pastTasks, $futureTasks);
        $response    = ['tasks' => $tasks];
        // return...
}
```

And If I retrieve only the futureTasks or pastTasks without array_merge, I get the desired output.

```
public function getTasks()
{
        $futureTasks = Task::whereDate('datetime', '>', Carbon::now())->orderBy('datetime', 'asc')->get();

        $response    = ['tasks' => $futureTasks];
        // return...
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the results are a collection. You can use the collection `merge` method.

```
public function getTasks()
{
    $futureTasks = Task::whereDate('datetime', '>', Carbon::now())
        ->orderBy('datetime', 'asc')
        ->get();

    $pastTasks = Task::whereDate('datetime', '<', Carbon::now())
        ->orderBy('datetime', 'desc')
        ->get();

    $tasks = $futureTasks->merge($pastTasks);
    $response = compact('tasks');
    // return...
}
```

Since you're using the `whereDate` condition, you're missing all the data from the present date based on your queries. You might want to check that.

Comment: That works perfectly. Like you suggested, I also switched to `where` instead of `whereDate` in order to sort by minutes and seconds not just the day. Much obliged, @Sandeesh.

Comment: @anonym no problem :)